# Get a token for the current logged in user, using MSAL.NET

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get a token for the current logged in user, using MSAL.NET

I'm getting a reference to PublicClientApplication, using the following API:

```
_clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
    .WithBroker()
    .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
    .Build();
```

Then, later in the code, I'm trying to call `AcquireTokenSilent` with the following code:

```
var firstAccount = Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication.OperatingSystemAccount;
authResult = await _clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
```

The call to `AcquireTokenSilent` thow an exception, with the following details:

```
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=WAM Error  Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Features.WamBroker.AadPlugin 
 Error Code: WAM_aad_provider_error_3399614466 
 Error Message:  
 WAM Error Message: V2Error: invalid_request AADSTS90002: Tenant '75950cd6-4468-4918-b750-966c6b4fa3d1' not found. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID and are signing into the correct cloud. Check with your subscription administrator, this may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant.
```

Interestingly, the SID '75950cd6-4468-4918-b750-966c6b4fa3d1' is **NOT** my tenant ID, and actually, I do not have this string anywhere in my code.

In the application registration, I set up the redirect URI to:
`ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/<my application SID>`. The application is registered for domain only, and the my device is domain joined.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Answer a comment from @Sridevi.
I'm following this demo almost to the letter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-desktop

With the following changes:

1. As a redirect URI, I wrote: `ms-appx-web://microsoft.aad.brokerplugin/<client SID>`
2. When building the MSAL application, I added `.WithBroker()` as mentioned above
3. For `firstAccount`, I do not take the first account from the list of acounts as in the tutorial (it is empty the first time), but I'm using the enum OperatingSystemAccount, mentioned above as well.

I would appreciate a sample or tutorial for getting this token otherwise.

Comment: Could you include what reference/document you followed for this that helps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Sridevi - In Updatesection